# HP Power Manager SMTP setup doesn't have space for username & password

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp, electrical-power, ups

Is there some way to configure HP Power Manager to *not* assume that there's an email server running locally?

We recently acquired an HP T1500 G3 UPS, which we're trying to control using HP Power Manager 4.2. The main reason we wanted to get this particular UPS is because it says it's capable of sending notifications (of the "Yo, the power's out, you may want to look into it" type) via email, as opposed to SNMP. Turns out, that's not entirely true.

The server is running Windows Server 2003. It is *not* running an email server of any sort - we do that via two different providers. Outlook email is provided by Verizon (not Exchange Server, just the outgoing and incoming email that ends up in Outlook), and our SMTP email service is provided by a small local company (i.e. a guy running an SMTP server on one of computers, for which we have a server name and password).[1]

When we use CDO to send auto-generated notification emails, we have to provide the SMTP server name, port, username, and password. The HP Power Manager interface only allows us to enter the server name and the username. Thus, not surprisingly, the emails never go anywhere.

Help?

[1] I'm afraid all this email and server stuff is pretty far above my head. If these details aren't sufficient, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't uncommon for applications to only support a server name and nothing else. These apps just don't support authenticating before they send. Nothing about that requires you to run your own mail server locally - it just means you need to list a mail server that will accept the mail without first authenticating. There are 2 ways to achieve that:

1. If the name of the mail server you give it is the mail server that hosts your mailboxes (Verizon, in your case) and the UPS alerts are only going to your mailboxes, you can list that server without even asking Verizon first. Their system will always receive mail for your email addresses so that will work.
2. If you supply a different mail server that isn't configured to host mail for your email addresses, that server will usually reject the mail unless you authenticate first. BUT, you can often convince the company to allow a specific IP address to relay through them. It sounds like this would be the likely option for the local company you use. They may or may not offer that service. Note that you would be able to give them a specific external IP address that all of the mail would be coming from which could get tricky if that box the UPS software runs on isn't already connected to the internet.

Really, #1 is by far the easiest solution. Good luck!

Comment: We tried #1 already, it doesn't work. And I can't find any sort of log file about the attempted emails, so I don't know if it's hitting an error somewhere or what. (If I hit "send test email", it gives me a lovely but totally false success message.)

Comment: @Martha: I would call Verizon and ask them which server name to list. I don't know how you determined what to put there but it probably isn't the same as the server name you connect your mailboxes to (but probably is the same as the hostname you point your MX records to). It is also possible antispam software is blocking it because it looks fishy. This is a very common request for a customer to make of a hosted email provider so they should have a standard response and if you have the right server listed, they should be able to track the message for you and tell you why it wasn't delivered.

Comment: @Martha: Also, the fact that you get a successful message almost certainly means the UPS software IS successfully handing off the message to the server you've specified which indicates the problem isn't on your end but at the provider. So again, I'd confirm with them you are using the right server name and if yes ask them to track one of your test messages to see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more detail on your email setup...

What does "our SMTP email service is provided by a small local company" mean?  On first reading, I figured that meant your clients were sending out with SMTP through that company.  If that's the case, you should be able to send email from the UPS using the same server.

OTOH, you say "Outlook email is provided by Verizon."  Is Verizon providing you a hosted Exchange environment?

One way or another, if all of your email service is outsourced, there should be a provider that will accept SMTP connections from your UPS and deliver those messages to a mailbox of your choosing.

Comment: "...you should be able to send email ... using the same server": How, if I'm given absolutely no opportunity to authenticate myself?

Answer (score 0):

The left-side menu is gone in all modern browsers. Wrote a quick guide how to get it to down again...
http://heineborn.com/tech/hp-power-manager-website-is-broke/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.